# How to fetch Data from Array in Angular js

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I am on a project in which I want to display data from array into `<li>` using Angular js

```
myid =[];
$scope.AddtoCart = function(){
myid.push( $scope.dataToCart);
srvaddtocart.addData(myid); 
//console.log($scope.SharedCart);    
}
  $scope.One = function(){
  $scope.AddtoCart();
  $scope.SharedCart = myid;
  console.log($scope.SharedCart);
  $("#close").click(function(){
    $(".oxy-product-cart").toggleClass("is-visible");
  });   
}
```

this is my js code where **SharedCart** is storing multiple ID 
the output of the SharedCart is something like this

```
[1190,902,123]
```

How to display this Array in my HTML page

- 1190
- 902
- 123

Comment: where do you want to show this array and how?.. please make your question a bit more clearer

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

Comment: don't use jquery in controller .

Comment: Was your question answered?

Answer (score 1):

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in SharedCart">{{item}}</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example you can add to your HTML view

```
{{myid}}

<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in myid">{{item}}</li>
</ul>
```